# Running a WPF online.. Azure Pref

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Is it possible to run a WPF online? I do not want to just deploy my WPF app so that the user downloads it and runs it on there computer. I want to be able to upload my WPF and when the user goes tot eh Mainpage its start the APP online.

I have looked at a ton of different ways but I cannot find anything that has a clean UI like building the WPF or windows form does.

Comment: Have you looked at Silverlight? Its basically what you describe. However, future support for it is dubious, as web pages are moving more towards HTML5 and Javascript these days.

Comment: @Joe Yea Silverlight wont work because I am needing it to open in edge which Silverlight is not compatible in.